# How can I draw a picture by Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, canvas

like this web: [placehold.it](http://placehold.it)

I wanna realize this web by Node.js (parse the url then draw the pic).

Before this, I knew can use [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) to draw pictures in Node.js.

But I wanna know can I realize this **just** by Node.js?

Comment: Node.js has no native image manipulation functionality, you could look at `node-gd` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gd) and see if that contains what you need.

Comment: In my company, we use Windows system. After company, I will use Linux to try this. By the way, what I want is just draw easy pictures, like rectangle with words. I would like not to use other npm package, maybe these drawing package based on `C++`. So I just ask, whether can drawing pictures by Node.js.

Comment: So to answer your question, no, Node.js doesn't have any image drawing capability without the use of an external plugin.

Comment: If you use an external library like `node-gd`, it will be compiled to work on the system you install it on, so it's likely the binary bindings will work on Windows too.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand my opition. In my company, I could only code on Windows, this npm package `node-gd`, its npm page says: `Sorry, will not build on Windows.`. I understand, server could be connected by all systems.But I must code in Windows now. After all, thanks a lot.